# Change the binary that Git uses to invoke GnuPG for signing commits?

Tags: git, gnupg

I'm signing my commits in Git using GnuPG. I'd prefer it greatly if Git would use `/usr/bin/gpg2` rather than `/usr/bin/gpg` for signing commits for some compatibility reasons.

Is there a Git configuration setting which will allow me to set which GnuPG binary to use during signing? I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try and set the right config:

```
 git config gpg.program gpg2
```

From [`git config` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> Use this custom program instead of "`gpg`" found on `$PATH` when making or verifying a PGP signature.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I missed this.

Comment: To be fair, this is somehow undocumented.